# LwM2M: connection between two LwM2M servers

Tags: eclipse, iot, m2m, oma, lwm2m

Is it possible that one LwM2M server will be connected to an other LwM2M server?

For example if one LwM2M can be on the gateway level and another LwM2M server is on the cloud, how could I connect the two servers?

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to get from such setup? If your goal is load balancing - there are different solutions for this.

Comment: Well it is more linked to local, remote deployment. Let's say in my local server (in the gateway) I will be able to manage my devices locally without the need to connect to the remote server (in the cloud). In the remote server I will be able to manage all gateway (can be more than one) and devices.

Comment: IIRC, Leshan can't work this way out of the box. LwM2M gateway/proxy are not a part of current Leshan implementation.

Comment: I see, is there any implementation of the LwM2M gateway? can't find one :(

Comment: At least I did not find any